# Green function and translational symmetry

Tags: differential-equations, green-function

I have met this problem in solving the classical field theory of a scalar field with a cubic term. I am able to solve exactly each equation, given in a form of odes, but this question escapes my current understanding and I will appreciate any clarification, even in the form of references.

I have to solve an ode in the form
$$
     y''(t)+\phi(t)y(t)=j(t).
$$
A straightforward approach I can devise is using Green function. So, I solve the equation
$$
     G''(t)+\phi(t)G(t)=\delta(t)
$$
and I would like to write
$$
     y(t)=y_0(t)+\int G(t,t')j(t')dt'.
$$
The problem is that, unless $\phi(t)$ preserves translation symmetry, the above equation cannot hold. This can be seen immediately by observing that one should have
$$
     G''(t,t')+\phi(t)G(t,t')=\delta(t-t')
$$
but this cannot be generally true as instead happens that
$$
     G''(t-t')+\phi(t-t')G(t-t')=\delta(t-t')
$$
and the solution should be written in another way. Is there a general approach to cope with a problem like this?

Comment: the Green function $G(t,t')$ of your differential equation is _defined_ as the solution of your fourth equation; your second equation only gives $G(t,0)$, which is not enough to reconstruct the full $G(t,t')$ unless $\phi(t)$ is in fact $t$-independent.

Comment: Thanks Carlo. I think that this is the main point. but can I start from $G(t,0)$ to reconstruct in some way $G(t,t')$?

Comment: one easy way to see that $G(t,t')$ cannot be reconstructed from $G(t,0)$, is to consider what would happen if the second-derivative term is absent; then you simply have $G(t,t')=\delta(t-t')/\phi(t')$ while $G(t,0)=\delta(t)/\phi(0)$; obviously, there is way to reconstruct $\phi(t)$ from $\phi(0)$ --- unless $\phi$ happens to be $t$-independent.

Comment: Did you mean "there is no way to reconstruct $\phi(t)$ ..."?